# Image DownScaling Issue

Tags: java, image, image-preloader

I need to re size from source image to target image , that's what i already did using following  code

```
public static BufferedImage getScaledSampledFilteredImage(
            BufferedImage img, int targetWidth, int targetHeight,
            boolean higherQuality) {

        ResampleOp resampleOp = new ResampleOp(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        resampleOp.setUnsharpenMask(AdvancedResizeOp.UnsharpenMask.VerySharp);
        resampleOp.setUnsharpenMask(AdvancedResizeOp.UnsharpenMask.Soft);
        BufferedImage rescaledImage = resampleOp.filter(img, null);

        return rescaledImage;
    }
```

and i am using

[Image Scaling library](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/)

but as you can see here i am getting dashed line , instead of i want continuous line.

can anyone guide me how can i achieve my goal ?

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

[image: Original Image]

[image: target image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set anti aliasing:

```
clearBuffer = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),
                            img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = clearBuffer.createGraphics();
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            graphics.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: thannks for your prompt reply. you mean to say my down scaled image is the img i will draw in last line of the code ?

Comment: Well. In my case, I was using Java 2D classes. I've downloaded the javadoc of the library you're using, but didn't understand it well. I didn't understand, in your code, why you `setUnsharpenMaks()` two times.

Comment: it is by mistaken written here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be useful for you, but I'm using this function when I want to re-scale my images :

```
public BufferedImage scaleImage(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String filename) {
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(filename);//path to image
            bi = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(ii.getImage(), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return bi;
    }
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these.  Tweak as necessary to suit your needs.

```
public static Image getScaled(final Image img, final int w, final int h) {
    return img.getScaledInstance(w, h, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
}

public static BufferedImage getScaled(final BufferedImage img, final int w, final int h) {
    final Image image = img.getScaledInstance(w, h, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    final BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());
    bufferedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    return bufferedImage;
}
```